# Split() function to split into groups, not individual elements - in R

Tags: r, split

Is there a way to split a dataframe into groups of elements and not individual elements. For example, in the following code

```
rs_scq_user_ <- split(regular_season, list(regular_season$season,
                regular_season$category, regular_season$question))
```

Say within the "season" column, I wanted

```
winter, spring
```

to stay together and

```
summer, fall
```

to stay together. How would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An option is to create a logical column for that.  Below, the 'flag' with `TRUE` values indicate 'winter', 'spring' and the `FALSE` would be automatically the res i.e. 'summer', fall' (assuming there are only 4 season in the data)

```
regular_season$flag <- with(regular_season, season %in% 
        c('winter', 'spring'))
```

Then, use `split` with 'category', 'question' and 'flag' instead of 'season'

```
lst1 <- split(regular_season, regular_season[c('category', 'question', 
         'flag')], drop = TRUE)
```

---

Or another option is `group_split` from `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
regular_season %>%
    group_split(category, question, flag = season %in% c('winter', 'spring'))
```

---

Or if we prefer to have a concatenated 'season' as new 'season'

```
regular_season %>%
    group_split(category, question, 
       season_concat = case_when(season %in% c('winter', 'spring') 
                 ~ 'winter_spring', TRUE ~ 'summer_fall'))
```

Comment: Thank you @akrun this is very helpful (as are all your other answers!)! I've seen some other users have links in their biographies to websites where people can buy them a coffee or something . You should let me know if you have anything like that, I'd love to return a favor to you for all your help

Comment: totally fine and people love your answers so I hope you get a lot of satisfaction!